# Deleting Non-Intersecting Geometries in PostGIS

Tags: geometry, geospatial, postgis, geodjango

I am working with geo spatial data (quite big one). Now the large data polygons are distributed on the map and i need to sub divide the area of interests (Where i have data) into tiles to further work on them.
Currently i am using postgis method ST_Square that creates the polygons of required size. Command to create tiles in postgis

```
ST_SquareGrid(0.2,geom)
```

geom is the polygon that i need to sub devide and 0.2 is the size in meters in which i am creating the tiles. I am using the projection 3857.

This functions seems to work completely fine until i found that its creating tiles for the area where no data is available. As shown in the image below. Only 3 squares should be there as 4th square does not have any data in it.

Can you help me control this so that it only creates the tiles where data is presents and avoid creating empty tiles.

[image]

(The solution can be in GeoDjango or PostGis)

Answer (score 3):

You could use `DELETE` in a subsequent step after generating the square grid. The idea is to remove those that do not intersect with your initial features. You have different approaches to solve this. The first uses spatial indices if they exist as it making use of [ST_Intersects](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Intersects.html).

```
DELETE FROM grid
  WHERE grid.gid NOT IN (
    SELECT grid.gid
    FROM grid, features 
    WHERE ST_Intersects (
      grid.geom,
      features.geom
    )
);
```

Whereas you could also use this query which makes use of [ST_Disjoint](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Disjoint.html) and doesn't use spatial indices, i.e. its performance will be slower.

```
DELETE FROM grid 
WHERE ST_Disjoint(
  geom, (SELECT geom FROM features)
);
```